# How to create waterfall layout in iOS 9+ with swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

I want to create a **waterfall layout** like in **pinterest app**.I tried different frameworks but none were compatible with swift 4. 
[image]

I tried using **PinterestLayout** ( https://github.com/MagicLab-team/PinterestLayout ) but the compiler is not supporting this framework.
I tried  **CollectionViewWaterfallLayout** ( https://github.com/ecerney/CollectionViewWaterfallLayout ) again the compiler not supporting it.

**Is it because I'm using swift 4? 
What are the alternative frameworks for such layouts which are compatible with swift 4 ?
Are the frameworks written in old version swift are not compatible with latest versions ?**

Comment: how about just creating a custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` between the two view-controllers? or if that is about the layout, how about creating a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`? tons of examples are available online and/or the Apple site...

Answer (score -3):

You can simply use custom UICollectionView for achieving this. 
Using Custom Layout you can design your collectionView according to the requirements.

It will be much easy and convenient in Swift.

Comment: Thank you @madhur . Is it possible that you can provide me an example?

Comment: you can take help from this tutorial :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2